# SQL statement returning "could not find file" while executing

Tags: vba, ms-access, inputbox

In my code, I am trying to use an input box to hold a user inputted value as a string, then use SQL to then update a field based on that.

My code is:

```
Dim strinput
Dim strsql

Call CreateRevisions

    strinput = InputBox(prompt:="Name of revision")
    
        If Not IsNull(strinput) Then
            'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            strsql = " UPDATE tblJobDetails.RevisionName"
            strsql = strsql & " SET tblJobDetails.RevisionName = '" & strinput & "'"
            strsql = strsql & " WHERE (((tblJobDetails.JobID)=[Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID]));"
            'DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
            CurrentDb.Execute strsql
            'docmd.setwarnings true
        End If
End Sub
```

When it runs, I get the prompt that fields are about to be updated, then the input box appears and allows me to enter something. I checked the value of `strinput` and it is holding the value correctly, but when I try to actually execute the SQL statement I can an interesting error I haven't run into before.

The error is :

```
Run-time error '3024':
Could not find file 'C\....
```

I have run various statements like this before with no problem. This is the first time I have tried using the input box however. What is causing that error?

I have tried changing it to `docmd` as well as adding in `debug.print`, but it still results in the same error.

Comment: What happens if you target the table like this? `UPDATE tblJobDetails SET`

Comment: The next Eagle Eye badge for @HansUp. :)

Comment: Seems I over complicated it when specifying. That did the trick,